# nativescript - tns run android webpack-cli error

Tags: webpack, nativescript, nativescript-vue, webpack-cli

After running tns run android, I bumped into this webpack error. I'm on the newest version of webpack
Any ideas is highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: try `"@nativescript/webpack": "^3.0.4",` and `ns clean`